# How to auto rename files url from localhost to liveserver or viceversa via git?

Tags: wordpress, git, file, migrate

I've done a number of web projects using Wordpress and I have no problem in migrating DB (using db-sync) and media upload (using rsync) from localhost to live server or viceversa.

But I'm using git for Wordpress theme files (.css and .php) and I have to repeatedly change the files url from http://localhost to http://www before pushing changes via git to live server or viceversa. It has became very tedious and prone to errors. So, I'm wondering if there's any command line I could use with git to automate this process??

I'm quite a newbie so please help me with this.

Thanks alot!

Comment: can you not use relative urls?

Comment: LOL. I'm so stupid. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute vs relative URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)